# Get the percentage of each element in a group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

```
id  column1   column2   column3   column4    columns5
1      a         b        a          b           x
2      b         a        c          b           y
3      c         b        a          c           x
```

Considering these groups:

```
group_1 = [a,b,c]
group_2 = [x,y,z]
```

How can I get this output:

```
%_a        %_b       %_c     %_x        %_y       %_z
0.3333   0.4167     0.25     0.667      0.333      0
```

because:

```
% of elements of group_1:  a=4/12, b=5/12, c=3/12
% of elements of group_2:  x=2/3, y=1/3, z=0
```

Comment: Can elements of `group_1` and `group_2` coexist in a same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `df.stack`:

```
group_1 = ['a','b','c']
group_2 = ['x','y','z']

s = df.stack()

res = (pd
       .concat(
           [s[s.isin(g)].value_counts(normalize=True)
            .reindex(g).fillna(0) 
            for g in [group_1, group_2]]
           )
       .to_frame().T.add_prefix('%_')
       )

res

        %_a       %_b   %_c       %_x       %_y  %_z
0  0.333333  0.416667  0.25  0.666667  0.333333  0.0
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to turn the `df` into a `pd.Series`.
- Now, for each group, we want to get only the values that belong to that particular group (using [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)), and to this selection we apply [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize` parameter set to `True`.
- Next, we chain [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to re-add any values from the group that are not present in the selection (i.e. `z` from `group_1`); we supply the value `0` for any such missing values by using [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).
- We use a list comprehension to apply this logic to both groups and use the result as input for `pd.concat` to get back one `Series`.
- Finally, we turn the `Series` into a `df` ([`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)), transpose it ([`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)), and add a prefix to the columns ([`df.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masks for this. For example:

```py
df.isin(group_1)
```

Will give you a boolean mask where the values of the DataFrame that are in the list `group_1` are True and the rest are False.
Then counting the number of values that are true is as simple as using the method `.sum()` twice or `.values.sum()` (ie. convert to numpy array and then sum the true values).

On the same way, you can iterate through the elements of the group and use a boolean mask to filter individual values eg.

```py
for i in group_1:
    print(f"Number of {i}= {(df==i).values.sum()}")
```

For the solution I would put the groups in a dictionary and then iterate through the dictionary:

```py
groups = {'group1': group_1, 'group2': group_2 }
results = {}
for group_name, group in groups.items():
    count_group = df.isin(group).values.sum()
    results[group_name] = {}
    for val in group:
        count_value = (df==val).values.sum()
        results[group_name][val] = count_value/count_group
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, elements of `group_1` and `group_2` can *not* coexist in a same column, a possible solution is, which is based on `numpy`:

```
def get_percs(df, group, cols):
    size = df.iloc[:,cols].values.size
    return np.sum(
        np.sum(df.iloc[:,cols].values ==
               np.array(group)[:,None][:,None], axis=2),
        axis=1) / size

get_percs(df, group_1, range(1,5)), get_percs(df, group_2, range(5,6))
```

Output:

```
(array([0.33333333, 0.41666667, 0.25      ]),
 array([0.66666667, 0.33333333, 0.        ]))
```

---

If the output is required to be a dataframe:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(get_percs(df, g[0], g[1]).reshape(1,-1), 
                        columns=[f'%_{x}' for x in g[0]]) 
           for g in zip([group_1, group_2], [range(1,5), range(5,6)])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        %_a       %_b   %_c       %_x       %_y  %_z
0  0.333333  0.416667  0.25  0.666667  0.333333  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) & [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) :

```
g1 = df.isin(group_1).sum().sum()
g2 = df.isin(group_2).sum().sum()
​
d = {**{k:g1 for k in group_1}, **{k:g2 for k in group_2}}
​
out = (
        df
          .set_index("id").melt()
           ["value"].value_counts().to_frame()
          .join(pd.Series(d).rename("c"), how="outer").fillna(0)
          .assign(temp_col= lambda x: x.pop("value").div(x.pop("c")))
          .T.sort_index(axis=1).add_prefix("%_").reset_index(drop=True)

      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

        %_a       %_b   %_c       %_x       %_y  %_z
0  0.333333  0.416667  0.25  0.666667  0.333333  0.0
```